# new Xcode + GitHub

Tags: xcode

A new Mac laptop with OSX 10.13 with Xcode 9 on it gets run time errors from a cloned the project that runs fine 10.8 OSX and Xcode 5

The C++ project throws Run-Time-Exception against one of the dylib's that are part of my project saying they can not be found in /usr/local/lib.

Below is the image trying to run the program on the new machine under new Xcode:

[image]

Below is a screenshot of trying to run the program from the Terminal:

[image]

[Those](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/231511/creating-a-project-inside-xcode) are instructions I followed to create the original project on the old machine.

How do I fix this runtime?

Comment: There is too much detail missing to generate meaningful answers. Also depending on the problem itself SO might be the better place to ask. But even there sharing the Github repository link (assuming it‘s public) and some more information about the build process/configuration will be required.

Comment: @nohillside, what details do you need? On both laptops I open the Xcode project, then hit `Cmd + B` to build it and then `Cmd + R` to run it. The configuration I am trying is currently `Debug`. And the repo is not public - still developing the project. If you need more details - just ask. I will be happy to provide as much of it as possible.

Comment: Also, when I run the binary from Xcode I have just a crash. In order to get something meaningful, I ran the program from the Terminal, where I got the nice window with the crash report and the message `Can't find the <library_name> inside /usr/local/lib`. Unfortunately Xcode does not provide the install functionality to make the dylib copy to /usr/local/lib and I presume it was done automatically on the old machine where the project was created.

Comment: Right now the only possible answer is "there is something missing in your build scripts and/or configuration". It might even be that you copied the missing library manually and just don't remember anymore (happens to me all the time). So without a lot more insights into your build scripts/config the problem can be more or less "anything".

Comment: And I would probably start with the crash within Xcode, not the missing library in /usr/local/lib.

Comment: @nohillside, and it is the same thing as its crashing in the startup code...

Comment: @nohillside, because the crash happens immediately upon start and ends up somewhere in the assembly code..

Comment: Please have a look at the [FAQ] and the help center to understand how this site works and what you could do to improve the question and have it reviewed for reopening. This will for sure require an edit which shares more insights about how your application builds, how the library is build and how this all plays together. Screenshots of related Xcode configure might also help.

Comment: @nohillside, I added a screenshots of running the program from Xcode and running it from the Terminal. About the build - everything is part of the big worspace inside Xcode project.. In order to build I just do, `Command+Shift+K`to clean and then `Command+B` to build. Build is successful, and I hit `Command+R` to run the program. The exact same process on the old machine let me execute the program after pressing `Command+R`.

Comment: Not sure what else is needed. If I'm missing smth - just ask.

Comment: Hey Igor. Any reason why this isn’t on stack overflow? Also, we don’t know what rte is. My main criticism is one question per question assuming the rte makes sense. Is it relevant somehow to answering the question or just back story. (If the latter, remove as much backstory since leaving one question should make things clear how to answer.)

Comment: @bmike, because it happens on Mac+Xcode during the "OS upgrade". And RTE is `Run-Time Exception`. Fixed it in the question as well. And this is one question - why the Mac where the project is made works fine, while the newer one where the project was tranferred thru the GitHub does not. And how do I fix it (hopefully without recreating). And the stuff you refer to RTE is a question. Thx.

Comment: Ok. I’ve chosen the question I think is more important and just helped streamline - less story and more facts. It still seems like it’s off topic since we’re not code level assistance, but let’s reopen it. If it gets closed again, we can see whether it’s on topic here or elsewhere or just that it’s not [MCVE enough](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: /usr/local files are ones that you installed not from Apple. You have it installed on your first mac but you have not installed it on the second. (Note to bmike the original question made this clearer and I think you fix the missing/bad library first - Xcode is not crashing - the program that is built is the thing that crashes.)

Comment: This question is a duplicate of the question you asked on the 10th of June. There’s no point in asking the same again, if you do not provide any new details. Please follow the instructions and answer from your old question.

Comment: @Mark, I didn't install anything. I am working from the Xcode and it doesn't have this function - only `Build` and `Run`.

Comment: @jksoegaard, if you are referring to this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362062/how-to-run-the-build-phase-in-xcode-as-root, then the suggestion didn't work as I explain in the last comment. If you meant something else - please explain.

Answer (score 1):

The first place to start would be checking the health and presence of the file in the dyld error:

```
/usr/local/lib/liblibdbwindow.dyld
```

Or fix the linking errors by changing what libraries the project expects.

Comment: ♦, the file is not present inside `/usr/local/lib`. And the project does build correctly - otherwise it would be impossible to run.

Comment: Sorry - I had a different context for "build correctly". I never think of the build as just to get an exit from the compiler, but that you can execute the program. Building a binary that can't even start seems like a participation medal of sorts.